# Multi channel funnels API Apps Script Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the new Multi Channel Funnels API through the Google apps script feature in Google spreadsheets. I am able to extract the data collection but am unable to parse it properly. It looks like some sort of json object but I cannot get the values to output on to the cell of the spreadsheet properly. It currently  looks like this:

```
 mcf:source 
{"primitiveValue":"(direct)"}   
{"primitiveValue":"Aug2012_enews_adoption"} 
{"primitiveValue":"Aug2012_enews_donation"}
```

I am unable to get rid of the primitive value key in the cells and just extract the value. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse these JSON values using `JSON.parse()` and then extract the value from the parsed object.